# how to retrieve one row at a time from my subquery

Tags: sql

I need to display a table with coloumns as TEST_NAME, TEST_PRODUCT, status1, status2. Here status1 should be the status of test_name selected in outer query.
Status 2 is also status of same test selected in outer query but in a different environment. I am having below problems with my query.

1. Subquery for status1/status2 is returning more than one row.
2. I am not sure how I can connect outer query and inner query so that I get the status of one that test which is selected in the outer query
3. I am also not sure if I have repeat the same tables twice both in subquery and outer query

---

```
select TEST_NAME, TEST_PRODUCT,

(
       SELECT  DR_STATUS FROM PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_DAILYRUN@FARMJANGO DAILYRUN,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_TEST@FARMJANGO TEST,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_ENV@FARMJANGO ENV WHERE 
         DAILYRUN.TEST_ID=TEST.ID AND 
TEST.TEST_PRODUCT IN ('Product Model', 'Product and Catalog Management','Product Hub', 'Product Hub Portal')
      AND  ENV.ENV_NAME LIKE :P2_ENV1  AND DAILYRUN.DR_DATE = to_char (to_date(:P2_DATE1,'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
) as status1,

(
       SELECT  DR_STATUS FROM PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_DAILYRUN@FARMJANGO DAILYRUN,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_TEST@FARMJANGO TEST,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_ENV@FARMJANGO ENV WHERE 
        DAILYRUN.TEST_ID=TEST.ID AND 
TEST.TEST_PRODUCT IN ('Product Model', 'Product and Catalog Management','Product Hub', 'Product Hub Portal')

      AND  ENV.ENV_NAME LIKE :P2_ENV2  AND DAILYRUN.DR_DATE = to_char (to_date(:P2_DATE2,'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
) as status2


 from PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_DAILYRUN@FARMJANGO DAILYRUN, PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_TEST@FARMJANGO TESTOUT
where  DAILYRUN.TEST_ID=TESTOUT.ID AND  TESTOUT.TEST_PRODUCT IN ('Product Model', 'Product and Catalog Management','Product Hub', 'Product Hub Portal')
```

Comment: Use 'TOP (1)'  in sub query

Comment: whether sub query returns same value multiple times or different values?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
SELECT TEST_NAME
    ,TEST_PRODUCT
    ,(
        SELECT TOP (1) DR_STATUS
        FROM PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_DAILYRUN@FARMJANGO DAILYRUN
            ,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_TEST@FARMJANGO TEST
            ,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_ENV@FARMJANGO ENV
        WHERE DAILYRUN.TEST_ID = TEST.ID
            AND TEST.TEST_PRODUCT IN (
                'Product Model'
                ,'Product and Catalog Management'
                ,'Product Hub'
                ,'Product Hub Portal'
                )
            AND ENV.ENV_NAME LIKE :P2_ENV1
            AND DAILYRUN.DR_DATE = to_char(to_date(:P2_DATE1, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        ) AS status1
    ,(
        SELECT TOP (1) DR_STATUS
        FROM PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_DAILYRUN@FARMJANGO DAILYRUN
            ,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_TEST@FARMJANGO TEST
            ,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_ENV@FARMJANGO ENV
        WHERE DAILYRUN.TEST_ID = TEST.ID
            AND TEST.TEST_PRODUCT IN (
                'Product Model'
                ,'Product and Catalog Management'
                ,'Product Hub'
                ,'Product Hub Portal'
                )
            AND ENV.ENV_NAME LIKE :P2_ENV2
            AND DAILYRUN.DR_DATE = to_char(to_date(:P2_DATE2, 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        ) AS status2
FROM PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_DAILYRUN@FARMJANGO DAILYRUN
    ,PRCQA.PRCBUILD_DR_TEST@FARMJANGO TESTOUT
WHERE DAILYRUN.TEST_ID = TESTOUT.ID
    AND TESTOUT.TEST_PRODUCT IN (
        'Product Model'
        ,'Product and Catalog Management'
        ,'Product Hub'
        ,'Product Hub Portal'
        )
```